# Publishing with TopologyManager, can I use a separate CmEnvironmentId?

Tags: publishing, web8, topology-manager

I have a scaled out publisher in SDL Tridion Web 8 with the CME on one machine (installed first) and then a Publisher on a separate machine.  In the install wizard at the last step it asks me about the Tridion CM Environment ID.  When I installed the CME I left the Tridion CM Environment ID as default, and also later when I installed the Publisher.  However, in the Publisher install it complained that it was not unique and instantly rolled back my install (without giving me any option to use another CM Environment ID.

Initially I created a mapping in PowerShell at the CME and when publishing I get the error

> "No mappings for CM Environment 'TridioncmUAT_Publisher', Publication
>   'tcm:0-11-1' and Purpose 'Staging' in Topology Manager"

I have 2 CM Environment Ids, 1 for the CME and 1 for the Publisher since the installer would not let me use the same one.

If I run the PowerShell command from the Publisher and configure publishing with Topology Manager, then I will be using the CM Environment ID of the Publisher machine.  So I could add my mappings from here.

However, will this cause any issues with other TopologyManager functions later on?  I am also using AudienceManager and the TopologyManager feature with it.

> CoreServiceRootUrl 'net.tcp://localhost:2660' -WebsiteRootUrl
>   'http://cmeurl:80' -AuthenticationType 'Windows' -UserName
>   'DMZ3\mtsuser' -Password '****' -TtmServiceUrl
>   'http://localhost:81/ttm201501'. CreateCMEntity: error Property
>   'CoreServiceRootUrl' of the item of type 'CmEnvironmentData' must be
>   unique. Source of conflict: 'TridioncmUAT_sqlcms'. MSI (s) (A8!98)
>   [18:15:04:559]: Product: SDL Web Topology Manager -- Property
>
> 'CoreServiceRootUrl' of the item of type 'CmEnvironmentData' must be
>   unique. Source of conflict: 'TridioncmUAT_sqlcms'.   Property
>   'CoreServiceRootUrl' of the item of type 'CmEnvironmentData' must be
>   unique. Source of conflict: 'TridioncmUAT_sqlcms'. CreateCMEntity:
>   Delete user account Tridion_Temp_User. CustomAction
>   CreateCMEntityExecute returned actual error code 1603 (note this may
>   not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the installer should not force you to create a new CM Environment in Topology Manager.  If it does, that should be reported as a defect.

As a work-around, you could create a dummy CM Environment (like you did), then change the `TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID` environment variable and use `Remove-TtmCmEnvironment` cmdlet to get rid of the dummy thing again.

Comment: Where would I change the TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID environment variable?

Comment: Updating the Computer Environment variable to the CME Environment name worked.  Needed to restart the Publisher service afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

CMEnvironmentId needs to be same across all scaled out instances. Even if their roles are different like the coreservice, publisher, workflow agent. The cm environment id is kept the same using the database name and db server name. If the installer is causing an issue then it should be investigated why.